# I have an old android tablet, how do I update it?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, rom

Ice cream OS on an Irulu x10 tablet, is there anyway to update to a new version of OS without cracking open the tablet to look at the CPU/board model numbers for an updated firmware flash?

Comment: Only if you find a custom ROM for that exact device model and the bootloader of the device can be unlocked. But the device is so old that it is unlikely to still find a ROM. But the hardware specs of that tablet is very low (1GB RAM) so newer Android versions will not really run well even if you would find a ROM.